# I am trying to run this function in python 3.4 version

Tags: python, python-3.4

I am trying to run this function in python 3.4 version.

```
tries = 0
answer = "Watson"
while(tries <= 3):
   print("What is the name of the computer that played on Jeopardy?")
   response = raw_input()
   tries = tries + 1
   if (response == "Watson"):
      print("That is right!")
      break;
   elif (tries == 3):
      print("Sorry. The answer is Watson.")
      break;
   else:
      print("Sorry. Try again.")
```

I am getting an error:

```
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined
```

Is there something different that I have to do for python version 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3 it is `input()` not `raw_input()`.

> `raw_input()` was renamed to `input()`.

[What is new in Python 3.](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html)